# code:3, Return on connection error CONNECTION_ERR in Transfer plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic2, transfer, ionic3

I am trying to download an pdf file form transfer plugin

```
fileTransfer.download(url+'?token=XXXXXX121b42867f03b7f1701e8f8656566a5', this.file.dataDirectory + file.filename).then((entry) => {
        loader.dismiss();

        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());

      }, (error) => {
        // handle error

        console.log(error);
        console.log('ERROR');


      });
```

i am always invoking error part of my transfer plugin.

I know it is something to do with my token i have tried my best but i wanted to know am i passing my token correctly an why i am always invoking error part.

Comment: what error are you getting in error callback?

Comment: i am not getting any error i am invoking error part of my plugin i am not getting download success part @Gandhi

Comment: do understand that. What is the error object getting printed when you did console.log?

Comment: `FileTransferError
body: null
code: 3
exception: "java.io.EOFException"
http_status: null
source: "http://xxx/misc/download/MOBINIUS SPORTS DAY 27TH MAY.pdf?token=xxxxxfa5dc755859b3121b42867f03b7f1701e8f8656566a5"
target: "file:///data/data/com.schneider.and/files/MOBINIUS SPORTS DAY 27TH MAY.pdf"
__proto__: Object
constructor: function (code, source, target, status, body, exception) {
__proto__: Object` @Gandhi

Comment: Error code 3 represents connection error. First try whether you are able to access the url directly in your mobile browser

Comment: yes i tried that one when i give my url with token in my browser it is downloading successfully that same url+token i am giving in transfer plugin it is not downloading and giving my error part @Gandhi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146385/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-gandhi).

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: no bro i solved it

Comment: @MohaGopi what is the issue?

Comment: i have answered it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was getting the file name as `demo sample.pdf` because of that space i was invoking error part

solution is `encodeURI(url)`

```
fileTransfer.download(encodeURI(url+'?token=XXXXXX121b42867f03b7f1701e8f8656566a5'), this.file.dataDirectory + file.filename).then((entry) => {
        loader.dismiss();

        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());

      }, (error) => {
        // handle error

        console.log(error);
        console.log('ERROR');


      });
```